# Node-RED cannot find local module

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I am developing a Node-RED Custom Node in TypeScript using a Nx monorepository with following hierarchy:

```
reponame
 + packages
 | + package-a
 | + package-b
 | + custom-node
```

The Custom Node imports *package-b* which imports *package-a* via `import { TestClass } from "@reponame/package-b"`. I performed `npm install`s in each package and it compiles to my repo's ./dist/ like a charm.

Now I'm struggeling to get my Custom Node into Node-RED. I did `npm install pathToRepo/dist/packages/custom-node` and the same for *package-a* and *package-b*.
However, when starting Node-RED this error is raised:
`Error: Cannot find module '@reponame/package-b'` in the .js-file containing the Custom Node.
In other words, my local dependencies in my custom node could not be resolved.
In addition to that, other dependecies on modules from the internet seem to be also NOT found.

I tried to do `npm install package-b` inside `pathToNodeRed/node_modules/@reponame/custom-node` but that did not work as it through errors while trying to fetch *package-a* from the internet.

How can I correctly resolve this issue?

Comment: Assuming you are running `npm install` in the NR userDir edit the question to show the `package.json` (also include the `package.json` from your node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing all dependencies including the local ones on monorepo level helped.

Just perform `npm install <path to package>` in `/reponame` for every dependency and delete the dependencies in each package using `npm uninstall <module name>`.